# Use tiff2pdf lib on AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, tiff2pdf

I'm trying to have a lambda that will convert tiff files into PDF files to later upload them into S3. For that I'm using the [tiff2pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tiff2pdf) library.

I copied the library executable inside of the lambda. But I'm encountering errors. I actually tried different approachs. I'll post here the latest one.

Basically, I followed these steps here:

1. I downloaded the source code of the `libtiff` library and compile it inside of an ec2 instance, using Amazon Linux.
2. Later on my lambda code base, I created a `bin` folder where I put the executable from the compilation of step 1.
3. I created a class to convert the pdf, that's suppose to execute the command `tiff2pdf -o file.pdf file.tiff`.
4. I uploaded my code base on the lambda created using Nodejs v18.

This is the class mentioned on point 3:

```js
import { exec } from 'child_process';
import { promisify } from 'util';
import { join } from 'path';
import { readFileSync, writeFileSync } from 'fs';
import * as path from 'path';

export default class TiffToPdfConverter {
  static async convert(inputPath, outputPath) {
    try {
      // Load the bundled tiff2pdf binary as an asset
      const tiff2pdfBinary = readFileSync(join(path.resolve(path.dirname(''), 'bin', 'tiff2pdf')));

      // Write the binary to a temporary file in the /tmp directory
      const tiff2pdfPath = '/tmp/tiff2pdf';
      writeFileSync(tiff2pdfPath, tiff2pdfBinary, { mode: 0o755 });

      // Execute the tiff2pdf conversion command using the provided binary path
      const command = `${tiff2pdfPath} -o ${outputPath} ${inputPath}`;
      console.log('command', command);
      await promisify(exec)(command);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error converting TIFF to PDF:', error);
      throw error;
    }
  }
}
```

I had to move the library inside of the `/tmp` library, because before I was having errors saying read only access. But even thought I keep having the following error:

```
/tmp/tiff2pdf: line 202: cd: /home/ec2-user/libtiff/tiff-4.5.0/tools: No such file or directory
/tmp/tiff2pdf: line 202: gcc: command not found
```

I noticed that inside of the executable there is a reference to that address. I just don't know how can I replace it.
This is the reference inside of tiff2pdf executable:

```bash
relink_command="(cd /home/ec2-user/libtiff/tiff-4.5.0/tools; { test -z \"\${LIBRARY_PATH+set}\" || unset LIBRARY_PATH || { LIBRARY_PATH=; export LIBRARY_PATH; }; }; { test -z \"\${COMPILER_PATH+set}\" || unset COMPILER_PATH || { COMPILER_PATH=; export COMPILER_PATH; }; }; { test -z \"\${GCC_EXEC_PREFIX+set}\" || unset GCC_EXEC_PREFIX || { GCC_EXEC_PREFIX=; export GCC_EXEC_PREFIX; }; }; { test -z \"\${LD_RUN_PATH+set}\" || unset LD_RUN_PATH || { LD_RUN_PATH=; export LD_RUN_PATH; }; }; { test -z \"\${LD_LIBRARY_PATH+set}\" || unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH || { LD_LIBRARY_PATH=; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH; }; }; PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin; export PATH; gcc -g -O2 -Wall -W -o \$progdir/\$file tiff2pdf.o  ../libtiff/.libs/libtiff.so ../port/.libs/libport.a -ljpeg -lz -lm -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/home/ec2-user/libtiff/tiff-4.5.0/libtiff/.libs -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/local/lib)"
```

Anybody able to help me here?